# How to ask a good question when I'm not sure what I'm looking for?

Tags: discussion, questions, downvotes, asking-questions

I am a student in computer science. I am technically a junior, but as far as my major is concerned I am on a sophomore level. Because of this and the fact that I didn't do any programming before starting school, sometimes I am presented with an issue either with a compiler or at run-time and simply have no clue what is causing the issue. Often it is something small or a conceptual problem with the way I am thinking about the structure.

I always try to google search the error code or what is happening and always look for answers in my text. I always try to the best of my ability to explain the problem well when I ask a question here. Yet I have had mixed response. Sometimes an overwhelming amount of helpful support, and sometimes rude comments. It seems I am being dismissed as lazy when really I have spent hours searching for a solution and trying different approaches.

It is not that I don't understand that my questions are clearly not presented correctly sometimes, but I really don't know how I am supposed to fix them without knowing what the problem really is in the first place.

A couple times I have been told I am not providing enough information. Sometimes this comes with a helpful suggestion about what information would be useful, but sometimes it does not, and usually if it doesn't I am clueless. Sometimes I am told that code that is from the professor that I cannot change, which I have pointed out, is just bad, and then my actual problem is ignored and my question downvoted. Not sure how I am supposed to fix that problem at all. Other times, once after explicitly explaining I was having trouble understanding how to use my debugger, I was told use a debugger. (What I needed was for someone to tell me to watch my variable values, not just "debug please").

I am not trying to rant about these frustrations, but I would like help understanding how to make sure that my questions are worded in a way that conveys my level of knowledge so that I can get answers or advice, or at the very least constructive criticism that helps me find an answer myself. Specifically how do I make sure that in a case where I am unsure of what is causing the problem I provide enough information to at least not get downvoted before I get an opportunity to fix the question to be specific on what the issue most probably is?

Comment: +1 for wanting to learn, and not going on to ask the same old way, but wanting to ask better. that is what its all about

Comment: Taking a cursory glance at your existing questions, you're above the majority of new users when it comes to phrasing of questions, but I can't give you much on the content since I'm not familiar with the subject areas that they're on. Most are: "X went wrong: I can't figure out why." + 200 lines of code. At the very least, you're putting effort into the creation of your question, which is appreciated. The fact that you've visited Meta to figure out how to improve also puts you above most.

Comment: Be as specific as you can, and make it clear that you are struggling to find the words. The effort to make it as clear as you can will be obvious.

Comment: @MDP: Indeed ridiculous; this site was not "made to answer people's questions", it was made to build up a database of good Q&A that will help future visitors. Also rep isn't to prevent spam (as you should know, there is no rep needed to post answers and questions) but is there as an incentive to post *high quality content*

Comment: The first rule is to collect all of the "standard" information, in a well-organized form.  This would be code or excerpts thereof, all error messages (quoted *exactly* and *completely*), exception stack trace (if present), and any relevant build details.  In particular make sure that the declarations of relevant variables are included in your description.

Answer (score 154, accepted):

When standing in front of a mountain that you have to move, it is indeed hard to decide where to begin, but it almost doesn't matter where, it matters that you start moving the first little stone, and not already half of the mountain.

Ok, Confucius was surely not a programmer, but let us start with the first small things that we can do to help you getting better at asking questions: understand why your questions were not well received. Oh, before we do that, let's consider two things:

> Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and
>   enthusiast programmers. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack
>   Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together
>   to *build a library of detailed answers to every question about
>   programming*.
>
> <sub>From [The Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), emphasis mine</sub>

What does that mean? First of all it means that we expect questions to be broad enough to *help future visitors* but not too broad *to not be answerable in our format* (well, and of course on topic).

> This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful
>
> <sub>The downvote button text</sub>

This means that you should not only do your research, but that we want to be able to see it. Saying "I google for hours" isn't enough, "I found this and that, but it didn't help me because of whatever" is much better.

Also -- and here is the hard part concerning your question title -- your question must be clear; this is particularly hard when you are not sure what you are looking for, but if you don't know what you really want to ask, how could we know, given that you are using such a low bandwidth form of communication as a textual question.

Now let's have a look at some of your questions.

### [Undefined reference to a class::function in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21438251/undefined-reference-to-a-classfunction-in-c)

This question has been closed as a duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816) which is our canonical question for undefined reference errors. This essentially means: you did not do enough research (or we don't know of any). Admittedly finding that question in Stack Overflow is not really easy:

- [standard search for "undefined reference to"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=undefined%20reference%20to)
- [google search for "undefined reference to"](http://google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+undefined+reference+to)

But we can do better:

- [better search for "undefined reference to"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=undefined%20reference%20to%20%20is%3aquestion)

So learn how to use all kind of search possibilities more efficiently.

Getting back to the error in question, what you should do is: start at the smallest level. Try to understand what an "undefined reference error" really *is*. Do that by research:

- [google search for "what is an undefined reference to error"](http://google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+what+is+an+undefined+reference+to+error)

Ok, the canonical question is also here hard to find, but should go through multiple ones, and following the duplicates is also a good idea.

Getting back to the introduction, what would have been a better question to ask? Possibly something like:

> I have looked at X and Y what an undefined reference error is, but I do not understand it. I also found <canonical question> but it didn't help me either because of <insert how your case isn't mentioned there and how it differs>.

Well, this question is actually not a good case to show a better question, because I cannot imagine how the canonical question will not answer any of those out there.

Anyways, you want to post code, and you did; but it isn't in a good format. To see what is going on, people have to go through multiple files, and if someone would want to try it on his own to see what happens, they had quite some work to do. In most cases, it is possible to reduce your code [to the least amount possible to show what is going on](http://sscce.org/). Do this. Put some effort into presenting your code, and don't just dump all the code you have at us. Most of the code will be irrelevant to the question you are going to ask. And as a positive side effect, in a lot of cases by reducing the amount of code, you will find the reason of the error.

Unfortunately, while even when this question is solved for your code, it is not what we are looking for on this site: It is very unlikely to help future visitors, unless it is uniquely different (it isn't).

### [Somehow my values don't seem to all be inserting into a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24085769/somehow-my-values-dont-seem-to-all-be-inserting-into-a-list)

Similar case here. You dumped even only a piece of code at us, without trying to narrow it down. Yes, it is hard to do that when you have a class given by a professor that you must use, and cannot easily paste (it surely is huge). But you reduce it to a testcase locally, and then post the testcase and tell us in all detail about the interface of the class.

You also say

> I am trying to use the Visual C++ debugger, but I am unfamiliar with it and it isn't giving me much insight.

Well, why don't you start there? You need to learn to debug, it's very essential, maybe more essential than writing code in the first place in some situations. So get used to it. If you have a problem with using it, narrow it down and ask a specific question (of course, try to answer the question yourself beforehand). With basic knowledge of a debugger you should have seen at least:

- where the code is hanging/looping
- what the values are that are used in any loop conditions

And even without a debugger, stuffing some printing statements here and there to see what the code is doing is possible too, and doesn't require any additional skill.

### [Beginner-Expected class name error in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21994876/beginner-expected-class-name-error-in-c)

Ok, that question starts with a rather bad title. You may be a beginner, but we don't care, and it doesn't matter. We expect the same effort from everyone. Stating your level of experience usually makes you a target, no matter what level.

Also here, there are lots of possible duplicates that solve the problem, have a look at the "related" bar on the right:

- [Error: "expected class name"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9796205/error-expected-class-name?rq=1)
- [expected class name before "{" token error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19994729/expected-class-name-before-token-error?rq=1)

and likely many many more if you go through some search results. Did you notice that list when you created your question? It is constantly changing while you write your question. Pay attention to it. Also here reducing it to a few lines testcase would have made it easier for everyone, and might have given you the right push to discover it on your own.

### [Recursive backtracking, showing the best solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24273012/recursive-backtracking-showing-the-best-solution)

Well, this question should probably be deleted because

- It is very specific to you and won't help any further visitor
- The problem isn't even in the code you posted!

Look carefully at the code you posted and try to read it from our point of view. We do not know what is

- Boat
- Boat::no_more
- Boat::print
- Boat::size
- Boat::can_place
- Boat::add_item
- Boat::remove_item
- the state (if any) of `boat`

Do you really expect us to reason in any way about the code without knowing all these things? We are not psychic, you know...

### [Expected primary expression before . when calling class function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22580902/expected-primary-expression-before-when-calling-class-function)

This would also greatly benefit from an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Again this is also a question not very helpful for future visitors. A more helpful version would have been had you asked specifically what a primary-expression is, or anything in that direction, that could help future visitors that face the same error. Also here some of the related questions have the same problem:

- [C++ Error - expected primary-expression before '.' token|](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18942205/c-error-expected-primary-expression-before-token?rq=1)
- [Friend Function, expected Primary Expression before . token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15326648/friend-function-expected-primary-expression-before-token?rq=1)

### [Format of constructor of an inherited class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21865915/format-of-constructor-of-an-inherited-class)

Also here, [do a search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=no+matching+function+for+call+to) and you will see quite some instances that have the same reason.

Also here you should have gone more to the ground and ask "What does this error mean? Why does it try to call that constructor? I thought I have that constructor on line XXX, why isn't it finding it" etc.

### Summary

- Improve your search skills
- Improve your search skills. No, thats not a duplicate. It really appears to me that you are missing obvious duplicates to your questions. I cannot look into your head as for why, but there seems to be a reason why you did not see what I mentioned above. Try to find out why.
- Start at the small things. Don't throw code in here and ask "why am I getting this error for that code". Try to understand error messages. Try to understand what exact syntactic construct is causing the error. Sometimes it might even be necessary to ask in multiple steps to get through some problem. Start with a stone, not with the whole mountain.
- Find some other help resource. We favor Q&A that will help later visitors. We are not a free debugging service. Although it is sometimes interesting to figure out what is causing an error, we hate the gazillionth instance of an undefined reference error. Ask questions that will help you (and others) in the future too by making them a little bit more general. In the question try to *actually understand* the error, and don't let your goal just be a fix to the code that you can copy paste.
- Be curious. Don't do [cargo cult](http://neurotheory.columbia.edu/~ken/cargo_cult.html) programming. When you see some code, try to understand every aspect of it. Don't copy code and then say "but it worked when I wrote the same thing yesterday in another project". Programming is not magic words to throw at a compiler and crossing fingers that it works.
- Improve your debugging skills, get used to a debugger (and maybe also a bit printf debugging).

Comment: Exceptional answer. We should show it to everyone on SO who got his first question downvoted.

Comment: Your answer makes this question a pearl. Hope it gets added in the FAQ.

Comment: Vote for this answer to be added when a user first registers on SO!!!

Comment: I would just like to say thank you a million times. This is exactly the kind of explanation I was looking for and I will be referring to it the next time I have a question. I really think this will help me ask questions in a better way and be a better member of this community

Comment: ...and as an additional statement: Not all problems are suitable for stack overflow. Some times, and especially when beginning to learn coding, you just need a teacher or a mentor. Thanks to both of you for an excellent question, and an even better answer!

Comment: This post should be used by universities. Many students learn something about software development itself ("how to do things"), but they don't learn how to handle programming problems when they occur. They often find SO and just drop their problem there.

Answer (score 21):

I'm going to focus on some more specific parts of [Recursive backtracking, showing the best solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24273012/recursive-backtracking-showing-the-best-solution).

#### Title

The title is meant to tell people what the problem is, as succinctly as possible.

**Your title is too vague.**
What are you backtracking on? *Why* are you doing it? What is "the best solution" anyway?

#### Introduction

Here's your introductory text. The fluff is crossed out:

> <strike>For school I am supposed to use</strike> recursive backtracking <strike>to solve a Boat puzzle. The user inputs a</strike> maximum weight <strike>for the boat, the</strike> amount of item types, and a weight and value for each item type.More than one of each item type can be placed on the <strike>boat</strike>.
>
> <strike>Our assignment states "The program should find a solution that</strike> fills the <strike>boat</strike> with selected <strike>valuable</strike> items such that the total value of the items in the boat is maximized while the total <strike>weight</strike> of the items stays within the <strike>weight</strike> capacity <strike>of the boat."</strike>
>
> <strike>It also has pretty specific template for the recursive backtracking algorithm.</strike>

So let's rephrase it:

> I have a container, which can hold up to a given capacity, or weight.
>
> There are several types of item that can be put in the container, and each has a weight and a value.
>
> I want to put the items in the container such that the value of the items is maximized.

#### What you did

> Currently I am using contiguous lists of items to store the possible items and the items on the boat. The item struct includes int members for weight, value, count (of how many times it is used) and a unique code for printing purposes. I then have a <strike>Boat</strike> class which contains data members max_weight, current_weight, value_sum, and members for each of the contiguous lists, and then member functions needed to solve the puzzle. All of my class functions seem to be working <strike>perfectly</strike> and my recursion is indeed displaying the correct answer given the example input.

Better. One much better way to phrase this, though, is graphically:

> I am storing the possible items and the items currently on the boat in lists.
>
> The items have these members:
>
> - `int weight`
> - `int value`
> - `int count   number of times used`
> - `int id      for printing purposes`
>
> The container has these members:
>
> - `int max_weight`
> - `int current_weight`
> - `int value_sum`
>
> and also has several contiguous lists and member functions for solving the problem.

#### Your problem

> <strike>The thing I can't figure out is the condition for extra credit, which is, "Modify your program so that it</strike> displays the best solution, which has the lowest total weight. If there are two solutions with the same total weight, break the tie by selecting the solution with the least items in it." <strike>I've looked at it for awhile, but I'm just not sure how I can change it make sure the weight is minimized while also maximizing the value.</strike>

Rephrasing again:

> Of the solutions that give the maximum total value, **I wish to find the solution that also has the lowest weight**, choosing the solution with the fewest items on draws.

#### Your code

> Here is the code for my <strike>solution</strike>:
>
> ```
>    bool solve(Boat &boat) {
>         if (boat.no_more()) {
>             boat.print();
>             return true;
>         }
>         else {
>             int pos;
>             for (int i = 0; i < boat.size(); i++){
>                 if (boat.can_place(i)) {
>                     pos = boat.add_item(i);
>                     bool solved = solve(boat);
>                     boat.remove_item(pos);
>                     if (solved) return true;
>                 }
>
>             }
>             return false;
>         }
>     }
> ```
>
> <strike>All functions do pretty much exactly what their name says.</strike> No more returns true if none of the possible items will fit on the boat. Size returns the size of the list of possible items. Adding and removing items change the item count data and also the <strike>Boat</strike> current_weight and value_sum members accordingly. Also the add_item, remove_item and can_place parameter is the index of the possible item that is being used. In order to make sure maximized value is found, the list of possible items is sorted in descending order by value in the <strike>Boat</strike>'s constructor, which takes a list of possible items as a parameter.

This might seem like you've done well, but this is mainly because strikethrough isn't a good way to give the problem.

Good code samples will be:

- **Complete.**

  The rule is that if you can't just copy the code, compile it and get *the same errors*, the code you're giving is near useless.
- **Abstracted**

  There is *absolutely no reason* to use `boat` here. The best thing to do is ignore the assignment and focus on the problem.
- **Small, but big enough**

  Don't blindly copy all of the code from your classes; hopefully most of it won't be related to the particular problem you are having.

  A good example, might be [Assignment within RAII scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24477791/assignment-within-raii-scope). I started with the trivial abstraction (the usage scenario and broken variants) but when I wanted other people to be able to run the code I gave a runnable file. Note that this does not have any `PyGILStateEnsure` calls, or similar as they weren't relevant. I think I ended up making that question significantly too long, though, so it's hardly perfect.

Only code that satisfies *all* of these is of sufficient quality to be part of a good question.

Further, formatting does wonders and you could have done with a list, but not as much as inline documentation.

#### The worst part

> Also here is an example of what input and output look like:
>
> <strike>IMAGE</strike>
>
> <strike>Any insight is greatly appreciated!</strike>

1. You put text in an image!! WHY?!
2. See 1.
3. Should have examples of what input should give what output

---

That's a preliminary on how to give better questions. It's not nearly comprehensive, but that was never the goal. I might finish this answer some other time, but it's usable as it is now.

Answer (score 5):

First off, I would like to point out that I believe that some people are just rude. When somebody says "I'm required to do X", it is rarely productive to say "Just change X!" -- which unfortunately is a common attitude. It is rude to say "you're just being lazy" instead of asking "what else have you tried?".

However, sometimes people tend to get short when faced with dozens of questions a day that are not fun to answer. What I would recommend is putting yourself in our shoes. Let's say somebody gave you a big printout of their program and said "I'm getting error X":

- Would you know what to do with it?
- Would you know what it means?
- Would you want to scan through that much code to figure out what their problem is?
- Would you be able to filter through all the details to figure out which ones are important to understand and which ones are irrelevant?
- Would you be interested in answering similar questions for several hours a week (or day)?

If you answered "No" to one or more of those questions, you can expect we won't do much better than you. If you wouldn't want to read 100 lines of code, we probably wouldn't either. If you wouldn't get any useful information out of "I am trying to use the Visual C++ debugger, but I am unfamiliar with it and it isn't giving me much insight", how would we?

**That said, kudos for wanting to be a programmer, wanting to be a good asker, and sticking it out!**

Think of it this way: asking a question on SO is really *programming SO*, where the output of the program is the answer to your question. Learning to ask questions is really just learning how to program SO. As you gain more experience, you will get to be a better "SO programmer", you will write better questions, and you will get better answers.

Comment: I'd like to add to your great answer that it is annoying to be faced with the dozens of questions a day. In fact, it is so annoying that professors, teacher's assistants and programming lab assistants get *paid* to do this.

Answer (score 4):

### Maybe try asking around in chat?

So if you're looking for ***a little*** guidance on how to ask a question, you could try asking around in a relevant [chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/), but make sure you follow each chat room's guidelines for what kind of questions they allow, if they allow programming questions at all.

I spend some time in [Tavern on the Meta](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta). You could try ask for a little guidance on how to ask a good question there, **but definitely don't try to ask your actual question there**, because everyone will tell you to just go ask it on Stack Overflow.

If, on the other hand, you just want a few pointers on how to ask a good question or make an existing question better, than people *may* (but no guarantees) offer a few tips here and there.

Answer (score -1):

It is not exactly possible to ask your questions on a site like this. Not knowing what you're looking for is synonymous with not having yet a mental model of the subject area/discipline. This is trivially handled in person-to-person situations, though.

As I see it, SO is not a site to teach you programming from scratch. It's not a replacement for textbooks, teachers/mentors, face-to-face interaction with other humans, etc. As you've yourself seen, it is essentially futile to attempt to ask questions here without having at least a well developed internal mental model of the subject area. It is so by design.

By necessity, your questions, when asked without yet having a rudimentary mental model of the subject, will be very much limited to the gaps in your own understanding. The complex interaction of such gaps is quite unique to you at a given moment. Thus your questions are very unlikely to help others, and there's no reason for them to be here in the first place. Generally speaking if a question/answer pair is only conceivably of use to one person, it doesn't belong here.

Since you're a student enrolled at a teaching institution, you should use the resources they have to help you learn. Ask your professors, TAs, lab staff. Ask other students. See if there's free tutoring available. Generally ask around. Heck, be a female chauvinist and ask if there are any gentlemen there to help you, or does a lady need to figure it out all by herself :)

None of this should mean that there is some fault in you, it's simply that SO is not for your questions as posted. There's little you can do to ask better questions without learning more about *the subject matter* first and developing a mental model of the discipline. Sure, once you get there, you can still ask bad questions: other answers here cover that.

Comment: Um, maybe perhaps *don't* suggest that the original poster use the fact that she's female to get help from males on learning how to program? Gender should have nothing to do with the process of learning how to become a software developer.

Comment: @Cupcake Sure. But if there's something one could use to one's advantage, I say **go for it**. Given how badly females are discriminated in the workplace, I see nothing wrong with using the female gender to one's advantage.

Comment: @KubaOber: I do see it as wrong. A woman who is supposed to be a programmer getting other male programmers to help her excessively or even do her work for her gives the entire gender a bad name and implies they are all less competent than male programmers.

Comment: @ZanLynx This doesn't imply anything about the gender, just that some guys who might not be bothered otherwise might now help.